# Cancelling edit mode inside SelectedIndexChanged event.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with Edit and Select buttons.

What I want to do is if I row is in Edit mode, and Select is clicked for another row, I want to end Edit mode on the other row and just select the new row.

The default behaviour is to select the new row and leave the edit row still in edit mode.

I know that has to be fixed here:

```
protected void gvRecordList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

But what is the syntax for exiting edit mode on a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
protected void gvRecordList_RowEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvRecordList.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    gvRecordList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    gvRecordList.DataBind();
}


protected void gvRecordList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gvRecordList.EditIndex = -1; // this is waht you need to do to reset your GridView from Edit Mode
    gvRecordList.DataSource = yourDataSource;
    gvRecordList.DataBind();
}
```